# Why are the factors p and q (for n) secret in Fiat-Shamir Authentication?

Tags: fiat-shamir

I am studying about this authentication and I don't understand why the factors of $n$ are kept secret as I can't see how they would give the prover or verifier anymore information.

My professor said that the verifier could learn the secret of the prover with the factors, but I don't understand how he would come about that mathematically. An explanation would be great to learn and understand this: Why are the factors $p$ and $q$ (for $n$) secret in Fiat-Shamir Authentication?

Answer (score 3):

**Knowledge of $p$ and $q$ makes computing square roots modulo $n=pq$ easy.**

Using the [Tonelli-Shanks algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm), one may determine square roots modulo $p$ and $q$ individually and then combine them to a square root modulo $n$ using the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Therefore, anyone who knows $p$ and $q$ can compute the prover's private key (which is a square root of the public key) to impersonate them.